# Which User authenticate Integrated Security?

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-authentication

When I use Integrated security for connecting to sql server with java and tomcat, which user is the one authenticating?

```
The user accessing the web page from different machine where the tomcat is (e.g.       
160.1.1.1/mywebpage)
```

or

```
The user where tomcat is located?
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be the account that the Tomcat service is running under.

Or, if you're running Tomcat from the command-line or a scheduled task, it's the account running the command-line, or configured in the scheduled task.

Comment: really?.. Do you know a way to authenticate the web user accesing the webpage?

Comment: The typical approach is to have the web application authenticate to the database using its account (eg. service account), and then authenticate the user to the web application.  The web application controls the user's access to the database.  It is possible for an IIS-based application to impersonate a logged-in user to the database, but I don't know if Tomcat supports this scenario.

Comment: can you explain your answer more clearly so other can learn too please?

Comment: @KickButtowski - In what way is my answer not clear?

Comment: I didn't mean there is any flaw in it. I just suggest to provide more info, so we can learn

Comment: Tomcat doesn't support this scenario. It may be possible to extend the existing SPNEGO support to do this. Investigating that has been on my TODO list for a while but it is still fairly near the bottom of what is an ever growing list.